# onChange or onKeyUp event takes previous value in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I've created form in ReactJS. I am fetching value in common method in `{key : value}` paired. but I am getting previous value in method.

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        {
            this.state = { name: "", age: 0 };
        }
    }

    inputChange = (key, value) => {
        this.setState({ [key] : value });
        console.log(this.state);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <form>
                <div>
                    Name : <input type="text" name="name" onKeyUp={(e) => this.inputChange('name', e.target.value)}></input>
                </div>
                <div>
                    Age : <input type="text" name="age" onKeyUp={(e) => this.inputChange('age', e.target.value)}></input>
                </div>
            </form>
        )
    }
```

I've attached the screenshot for better understanding.
[image]

Comment: What do you want to do in response to the state changing? Code that is responding to state changes might be better suited for another [lifecycle method](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#the-component-lifecycle).

Comment: I just want to set the data in a state. so when I submit the form, i will pass the whole updated state.

Comment: If you're logging it for debugging, then using my solution to check the value is fine . When the user submits the form, the state will be the value you expect.

Comment: ok. I got your point. so, I don't need to worry if I want to submit the data. Am I right?

Comment: If you add a `onSubmit` handle to the `<form>`, the local state will be the latest values when the form is submitted. Shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`setState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) enqueues a change to the state, but it doesn't happen immediately. If you need to do something after the state has changed, you can pass a second callback argument to `setState`:

```js
inputChange = (key, value) => {
  this.setState({ [key] : value }, () => {
    console.log(this.state);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This will do exactly what you need.

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      name: '',
      age: ''
    }
  }

  handleInput(option, event){
      if (option === 'name') {
       this.setState({
            name: event.target.value
        }, () => {
          console.log("Name: ", this.state.name)
        });
      }
      else if (option === 'age'){
        this.setState({
            age: event.target.value
        }, () => {
          console.log("Age: ", this.state.age)
        });
      }
  }

  render() {
        return (
          <div>
            <div>
              <header>Name: </header>
              <input type="text" onChange={this.handleInput.bind(this, 'name')}/>
              <header>Age: </header>
              <input type="text" onChange={this.handleInput.bind(this, 'age')}/>
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: @josemantindev : yes, but I want to you single method rather then creating separate methods for all controls.

Comment: @UbiquitousDevelopers Ok, I modifed my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

update 2022

with functional components using useState hook this does not work longer, you have to use it in useEffect to update after rendering.

```
State updates from the useState() and useReducer() Hooks don't support the second callback argument. To execute a side effect after rendering, declare it in the component body with useEffect().
```